# DIV Contenteditable expand problem

Tags: html, resize, contenteditable, designmode

I have a div with contenteditable set to true to act as a text input.
Now usually, it expands as some text reaches the end of the div, but if I resize the div, this stops happening. The browser no more does this. I tried to set the height after resizing it to auto, but it didn't help either.

Please help me on that one.
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you've set the height absolute the browser will handle it absolute.
So apply the following css rules to your div:

```
#yourdiv {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you have an example: http://html5demos.com/contenteditable look at it's source code with chrome or firebug.

It all goes around the width, height, and overflow. You should also be carefull with the word-wrap property. Check it out! :)